# Multisite Smtp Server

Tags: multisite

So i am running into a problem.

I have wordpress multisite but problem is that sending smtp emails.

what i did is

Make a smtp server in plesk.

use the credentials from smtp server.

Then use DNS in the domain to send emails "From" address.

Problem is that not all of my customers knows how to add DNS. is there anyway i can add these DNS entries from Plesk?

I know there are DNS settings but i am not sure if that will overwrite the customer DNS or not?

For example:

blog name: xyz.com
admin email: test@123.com

Comment: What do you mean by this bit: "Then use DNS in the domain to send emails "From" address" ? Do you mean set up the SPF records for your new SMTP server on those domains? No, you can't modify DNS records for your customers that you don't host yourself.

Comment: yes you are right the SPF and DKIM records. 
ah. so is there anyway to achieve this? without giving troubles to customer?

Answer (score 0):

Customers have nothing to do with SPF and DKIM records of your website. If there are any SPF and DKIM records that require an update, you should be doing it in your cPanel->Zone Editor or DNS setting in the CDN. If you are not sure, contact your hosting company to help you with that.

Comment: But this is about sending email from the customer domains. If I want to send an email from "orders@customer.com" then the SMTP server I use must be listed on the SPF record in the customer's DNS. If OP controls the customer's DNS then that's OK, but it doesn't sound like that's the case here.

Comment: I think we need more clarity on the question. Correct me where I am wrong. 1- You have a WordPress multisite setup. 2- You configured SMPT using Plesk on your WordPress multisite. 3- Who are the Customers and what is the relation of Customer Domains with your domain? Are your customer using their own domains OR are they admins of your subsites?

Comment: So we are doing  PaaS where our subsite (sub domains and also individual domains via A record) can send emails. Upto now if i can Add SPF nad DKIM regards then all is good however this is not the case. If you think about AMAZON SES they are doing the same by autheticating domains and asking the customer to.add dkim to thier domains. I want to avoid this but i am banging my head into steel which is only hurting abd no outcome.